# Installing nltk for Python 3.4 on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, nltk, python-3.4

I have been attempting to get nltk running under python 3.4 without success. Using the instructions at http://www.nltk.org/install.html:

sudo pip install -U nltk

This works for 2.7 that is preinstalled on the Mac, however when using

sudo pip3 install -U nltk

to try and install under 3.4 I get the following error:

```
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

  warnings.warn(msg)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'

  warnings.warn(msg)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'

  warnings.warn(msg)

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: setup.py --help-commands

   or: setup.py cmd --help



error: invalid command 'bdist_egg'

/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/distribute-0.6.21-py3.4.egg

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools

    raise ImportError

ImportError



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/setup.py", line 23, in <module>

    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools

    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download

    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 116, in _build_egg

    raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')

OSError: Could not build the egg.
```

Python 3.4 was installed with brew and both bumpy and setuptools are installed correctly. I have seen hints of this problem through some goggling but no definitive answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just downloaded the 3.0.0b2 `.tar.gz` file from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk), unzipped it, and ran

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

in the unzipped directory and everything worked fine. I had the same issue trying to install from `pip3`. I should also note that I use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) for Python and all the rest, but hopefully that won't make a difference.

Comment: While thinking further, I tried the same thing and it worked too.So the upshot is that the nltk docs and pip method looks to be broken in this circumstance but nltk can be installed with manual download and running setup.py